# Изменение значения элемента 2мерного массива по указателю.

Tags: массивы, указатели, c++

Здравствуйте! Возникла следующая проблема.

```
char **map = new char*[s];  //так я объявляю двумерный динамический массив
for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)  
map[i] = new char[c];
```

Далее я его инициализирую. При при попытке вывести его на экран все проходит гладко.

```
cout << map[i][j]; // так я вывожу каждый элемент массива(в цикле)
```

Но при попытке изменить значение элемента массива, программа завершается ошибкой.

```
map[x][y] = 'H'; // так я пытаюсь присвоить нужному элементу массива конкретное значение.
```

Собственно вот ошибка:
**"Unhandled exception at 0x00fa16f1 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00fa89b5."**

Я догадываюсь, что т.к. используются указатели, то нельзя вот так напрямую изменить значение в памяти, на которое они указывают, но как сделать это правильно я не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По мотивам Вашего кода сделал пример. Все работает, как ожидалось и не падает

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   int s = 5;
   int c = 4;
   char **map = new char*[s];  //так я объявляю двумерный динамический массив
   for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)  
     map[i] = new char[c];

   for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
         map[i][j] = i*j;
   for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
         cout << (int)map[i][j] << " ";
      cout << endl;
   }
   // здесь ещё нужно вставить освобождение памяти
   for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
     free(map[i]);
   free(map);
   return 0;
}
```

Если у Ваш код падает - приведите его полностью (либо соберите минимальный пример, который также падает).

Comment: Вот этот код завершается с такой же ошибкой.

   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int s = 5;
   int c = 4;
   char **map = new char*[s];  //так я объявляю двумерный динамический массив
   for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)  
     map[i] = new char[c];

map[0]  = "ooo";
map[1]  = "ooo";
map[2]  = "ooo";
map[3]  = "ooo";
map[4]  = "ooo";

map[0][0] = 'a';

   for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
         cout << map[i][j] << " ";
      cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}

Comment: а так нельзя писать. 

Вместо

    map[0] = "ooo";

нужно писать

    strcpy(map[0], "ooo");

и не забыть

    #include <cstring>

Либо не забивать себе голову и использовать `std::vector<string>`.

Comment: И что Вы хотели? Сначала инициализируете массив map, а потом его портите.

@KoVadim так писать можно, просто нужно понимать, что из этого получается...

Comment: @iterq, падает, т.к. Вы пытаетесь модифицировать константы.

Вместо 

    map[0] = "ooo";

напишите

    map[0] = strdup("ooo");

но тут Вы потеряете инициализацию по new char[c], хотя Вы и так теряете ее.

Comment: и получите утечку памяти:)

Comment: @alexlz, ну почему же порчу. Изменяю:)

Comment: @avp меня терзают смутные сомнения. Я не помню, где и что я читал, но где-то попадалась рекомендация не смешивать new и malloc (в strdup наверняка он).

Но точнее не помню

Comment: @KoVadim, огромное спасибо. Все получилось, если можно, то в 2х словах.. почему нельзя было писать так, как я писал?

Comment: да, лучше не смешивать. и да, strdup использует malloc

    char * strdup(const char *str) {
       size_t siz;
       char *copy;
       siz = strlen(str) + 1;
       if ((copy = malloc(siz)) == NULL)
         return(NULL);
       (void)memcpy(copy, str, siz);
       return(copy);
    }

А почему нельзя просто написать `=`? код, из вопроса - это не плюсы, это си. А там никто массив не будет копировать просто так (да, "ооо" это массив с 4 элементов). А просто скопирует указатель (параллельно создав утечку). А константные данные компилятор имеет право разместить в "константной памяти".

Comment: @KoVadim, естественно память теряется. Просто про ее начальное выделение, увидев map[0] = "ooo"; вообще забыл.

@alexlz, да не рекомендуется. Но это важно для классов (деструктор не вызовется) или если использовать свой аллокатор, а для примитивов все равно.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, происходит обращение к несуществующей ячейке (X д.б. в диапазоне (0..s], Y д.б. в диапазоне (0..c]).

S - кол-во строк

Comment: Я это проверил, в момент ошибки IDE делает паузу и можно посмотреть значения всех переменных. С ними все в порядке.  
Ошибка возникает именно в случае использования указателей для объявления массива.  Если объявлять как обычно (char map[s][c];), то все работает.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять имя массива с map на myMap... Возможно, присутствует конфликт имен (с std::map)

Comment: @iterq, код в студию.

Comment: @avp, я привел более короткий пример кода в комментарии к ответу KoVadim. Он завершается точно такой же ошибкой.